# Select MIN of a function and create a virtual table

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I'm needing to take the min value of a function, if the min value he put on a 0 virtal column, if not, place 1.

```
SELECT ID, Name, (X + Y) AS TOTAL, MIN(TOTAL) AS MINVALUE FROM TABLE
```

Example

```
    ID    Name   TOTAL   MINVALUE
    1     item    22        0
    1     item    33        1
    1     item    50        1
    2     item2   200       1
    2     item2   30        0
```

Comment: you'd need a subselect. min() is an aggregate function, and can only work once the entire result set is available, but you're using it in a per-row basis, so every row is automatically its own max/min simultaneously. `selecct min(total) from (select x+y as total from ...) as foo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this using window functions and `case`:

```
select id, name, (x + y) as total,
       (case when (x + y) = min(x + y) over (partition by id)
             then 0 else 1
        end) as IsNotMinValue
from t;
```

I normally follow the Unix convention of "0" being false and "1" (actually not-"0") being true.  Hence, I named the flag `IsNotMinValue` because that is how I would interpret it.

Comment: total isn't a column, but this should be easy to fix and should work